# Kill for a young body

Tags: strategy, probability

FROM 2013 [Real Playing Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Playing_Game).

Here's the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRhfOW4S8xs).

You are an old, deathly-ill multimillionaire. A biotech company has developed some brain transfer technology and offers you the chance to participate in a game to win a young body if you pay the asking price of 5 billion dollars.

The catch: You will have to play to the death against 9 other players and only the winner will keep the young body.

So you accept the deal and wake up in a Young Body in an abandoned building and soon you find the other 9 players. In total there are 5 men and 5 women (all young).

After some walking you and the other players find the game master and he shows you some holograms of 10 old people (6 men and 4 women) with some bio-briefing. You can't identify which old person is inside of which young body. Even gender cant help you identify the person because some guy chose a women as his new body.

Now the game rules:

- They have to kill one person every hour or the game will kill one of them at random
- After they kill someone, the killer has 10 minutes to select the correct hologram of his/her victim or they will be killed. They will also be killed if they make the wrong choice.
- If killer guesses right, the victim's hologram disappears. If the killer guesses wrong, both the right victim and the now-dead killer's dissapear.
- You know which is your own hologram

So what is the best strategy to win this game? Here are some suggested possibilities:

- Go hide and hope you aren't selected are random.
- Kill someone and choose a hologram at random. Would you kill a man or woman?
- Start with one strategy and switch once less players remain.
- Form an alliance as long that is mutually beneficial to the other player. Be careful! Don't share your own identity or the other player will kill you for sure.

Comment: Please could donwvoter leave a comment so I could improve the puzzle.

Comment: I don't understand the rules of the game. Is the idea that a person can kill another whenever he or she wishes? Or is this something that happens exactly once an hour? Also, is the assertion that 5 men chose male bodies and only one chose female?

Comment: @JulianRosen Isnt an assertion. Could happen 2 men chose female and one women choose male. The idea is someone have to die every hour or the game chose random. You can `try` kill someone, Wait for another one do the kill or wait for the random.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes down to 2 people, you'll want to kill the other person, as you know 100% who the other person is.

At the beginning you do not want to kill anyone, as you have only 1/10th of the chance of dieing, where if you killed someone you have 8/9ths chance of picking the wrong person and dieing.

If you had a way to force other people to kill each other, that would be the best strategy, as there is no risk here. Other than that, hang tight until the end.

P.S. Just because one person changed sex doesn't mean others didn't as well... so guessing based on sex is to no advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Until there's more than one opponent, the chances of being killed by the timer is always less or equal than the chances of being killed by choosing the wrong hologram. Besides, you'll be risking getting killed in battle.

*The exception is when there's only one person left on a gender*. But this exception will only work *if* you're sure there was only one gender swap. There's one man in a body of a woman. If you're this man, wait until there's only one left in a gender, then try to kill him/her. If you're not, wait until there's only one man left.

Have some allies to reduce the chances of battle in case you cross someone by chance, but make sure you keep a low profile from the beginning and avoid confrontations. The key is to rely on chance, survive, and wait until the body count is high enough, or in the best case scenario, the opponents were all killed off.